# Bind9, Ubuntu 14.04, rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused, no error logs

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I'm attempting to start a DNS slave and It was working yesterday. I'm not sure what I changed but it is giving me 
(today I added a different method of getting the zone files, but it didn't change any options. Just the zones themselves.

```
 rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

I'm not sure where to look for the logs. I have checked

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/messages(doesn't exist)
```

Every issue I look at they have some way of seeing where the error is and I can not find any log files.

Comment: The error from `rndc` is quite likely caused by `named` not even running in the first place (`rndc` talks to `named`, if `named` isn't there it fails). As for the problem itself finding the logs would surely be helpful, however `named-checkconf -zj` (optionally with `-t ....` if named runs chrooted) may be a good starting point that doesn't rely on logs.

Comment: Okay, I did it and I found that I had two options {} one in the named.conf and one in named.conf.options. Now it's says 
    zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Which I assume means that it's fine. But I still get the error while trying to start bind service.

Comment: What does "the error" refer to, same as in the question? You can't **start** named using rndc, for one thing it has no such option and it's also not possible conceptually; as I explained rndc is a tool which communicates with named, it requires named to already run before it can be used.

Comment: I understand the error now. I misunderstood what rndc was. I have a shell script that somewhere was trying to start rndc somehow. When I started bind via service instead of the script everything works fine. Then my shell script works as long as bind is running. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the real problem was a configuration error which caused `named` to fail to start. (Found with `named-checkconf -zj`, but the error should also be in the logs.)

However, it's worth noting what can be concluded from the `rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused` error.

First of all, the error from `rndc` is usually not the real problem but rather just a result of how `rndc` operates in conjunction with an actual problem with `named`.

`rndc` is a tool that allows you to control `named` through various commands, it does so by communicating with a running `named` process.
That also means that whenever `named` is not already running (as in the case where it failed to start because of a configuration error), `rndc` is effectively not usable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in 16.04 with the same error message.  The permissions on /etc/bind were wrong due to pilot error.  The correct permissions are:

```
drw-r-sr-- 3 root bind 4096 Nov 25 16:21 /etc/bind
```

I had executed a chmod without checking the pre-existing permissions.  The setgid bit got me.